# How to escape + in auto hot keys

Tags: autohotkey

How do I escape the + (plus) in AutoHotkeys?

I've tried:

{+}

'+

+

None of those works

Here is my script:

```
   ^Numpad5::
     SendInput, myemailAddress+ApproveEmailTest@gmail.com
   Return
```

Comment: Have you tried `+ (a backtick) ?

Comment: `{+}` works for me in AHK 1.1.30.1. You can also use SendRaw

Comment: @wOxxOm that worked after I re-compiled AGAIN!  Maybe something was cached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

The brackets finally worked. I tried those, but maybe something did not compile properly? Thanks wOxxOm

```
^Numpad5::
  SendInput, myemailAddress{+}ApproveEmailTest@gmail.com
Return
```